# Facebook FQL only can run on the developer's account

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The code only can run on the developer's Android app which is logged by developer's fb account.
I don't know what happened on it?
Is there anything else I need to set?

```
SELECT post_id,updated_time,message FROM stream WHERE source_id="+ userID +" and actor_id="+userID+" and type IN (46,66,80,128,247,257,285) LIMIT 120
```

---

but that can run ..

```
"SELECT name,username, birthday_date,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
+ "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
```

---

that's  getData Method

```
public void GetDate(){


    String fqlQuery = "SELECT post_id,updated_time,message FROM stream WHERE source_id="+ userID +" and actor_id="+userID+" and type IN (46,66,80,128,247,257,285) LIMIT 120";      

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            try {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    // Check if there is extra data
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("data") != null) {                         

                        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(graphObject.getProperty("data").toString());

                        Log.e("JSONARRAY",graphObject.getProperty("data").toString());


                        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject dataObject = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);                          
                            String postID = dataObject.getString("post_id");
                            String postTime = dataObject.getString("updated_time");
                            String postMessage = dataObject.getString("message");
                            Log.e("postID",postID); 
                            Log.e("postTime",postTimev);
                            Log.e("postMessage",postMessage);
                        }                       
                    } else if (error != null) {
                    }
                }else{
                }
                //Log.e("Result: ", response.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    finish();

}
```

I use Facebook Developer Tool to test it, it can work ....
Link:https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

---

Permissions：(I have done)

1. All of step on Facebook Developer Android Page -Getting Started
2. Get Access Token by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

check whether sandbox mode is on or off. Make sandbox mode to off. Until sandbox is on your app is visible  to developers only. Make the changes in facebook app page

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to lay in how you are executing the query. Show us the code you use and how you are authenticating before running the FQL. Have you also made sure you have been granted the permissions you need?